# Reading/using format YYYYMMDD and "0" values in date field

Tags: date, format, sas

We have a system feed that's changing...it's currently Julian date and is converting to YYYYMMDD--although for blank values they're feeding in "0".  Not sure what format it's coming in as...

First, I took out the 0's by doing "if XXXfield = 0 then XXXfield = ' ' which returns a "." for that record.  Then I tried to code using "format XXXfield YYMMDD8." and that's returning blanks for anything with a date.  I'm not creating the table, just reading it in....how can I successfully get the date to be a date with no "0" values for blanks and in a format that I can use in SAS (ie XXXfield >= Xdate)??  Thanks in advance for your advice!

Sample Data (one blank and 4 with values):

```
reporting_date
0
20141122
20130604
20130626
20140930
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to the '0' dates?  And how are you reading this into SAS - is this coming in from a database, a text file, something else?

Comment: I would like the '0' dates to be blank ultimately.  I'm reading it from a SAS data set on our server.

Comment: Originally, the data is pushed from a sales system and this format is the format they have availalbe to send it to us in.

Comment: @BellyDanceCostumes, some tips that you can keep in mind when you are about to post your next question. 1. Put yourself in the readers position and make sure that youself are able to understand your question. 2. Make sure that you have a working dataset in your question, like the `data work.have;` that I posted below. 3. Make sure that you add the actual code you have tried so far. Those three will help you to get an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

The format of `reporting_date` is `BEST12.` according to your comment below.

```
data work.have;
input reporting_date BEST12.;
datalines;
0
20141122
20130604
20130626
20140930
;
run;
```

So, one way to make SAS to interpret `reporting_date` as an actual date is to temporarly format it as as string and thereafter convert it with `YYMMDD10.` as the format.

```
proc sql;
  create table work.want as
   select input(put(t1.reporting_date, 8.), YYMMDD10.) format=YYMMDDn8. as reporting_date
   from work.have t1;
;
run;
```

In this case,

- `put` converts it to a string with eight characters as the width,
- `input` will convert the string to an actual SAS date, and
- `format` will display the date in a human readable way.

The third bullet is optional, and the value of `format` is just one of many [date and time formats](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm) available. The conversion also takes care of rows with `0` as value and transforms them to missing (`.`).

Now, when you have the column as a SAS date, you are ready to filter it:

```
proc sql;
create table work.filter as
  select t1.reporting_date
  from work.want t1
  where t1.reporting_date > '01JUL2013'd
;
run;
```

But instead of make these workarounds, you should look into changing the format in the job where you read this column into the SAS dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I'm not using an input statement as I'm reading records from an existing data set.  I have over a million records in this data set, so it's not feasible to read each one in each time via an input statement.  Here's the code I have so far to test this....it isn't working....all dates are coming up blank.

Comment: This reads in data from data set located on our SAS server, direct feed...no input, not creating the data set fresh.                                                                                                  data test;
 set k.test_dates;
 if actual_end_date = 0 then actual_end_date = ' ';
 run;
data test1;
 set test;
 format reporting_date yymmdd8.;
 run;

Comment: Can you please run the following code: PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_VCOLUMN AS 
   SELECT t1.name, 
          t1.type, 
          t1.format
      FROM SASHELP.VCOLUMN t1
      WHERE t1.libname = 'K' AND t1.memname = 'TEST_DATES' AND t1.name = 'ACTUAL_END_DATE';
QUIT;
RUN;

Comment: And post the result in the comments.

Comment: I get 0 rows and 3 columns named "name, type and format".  It's pointing to the right libname, data set is named test_dates, field exists named actual_end_date.

Comment: I think this is what you were after.  Name:  actual_end_date, Type:  Numeric, Length: 8, Format: BEST12., Informat:  BEST12.  Does that help figure out why I'm getting blanks?

Comment: Yes, that helped. If the answer above helps you, you should edit your question and add that your input format is `BEST12.`. This will help other readers to get your problem.